# Clojure yagni "could not find any references" to a proxy Callable instance

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use https://github.com/venantius/yagni

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
=================== WARNING: Parents ======================
==    Could not find any references to the following     ==
===========================================================

my-proj.my-ns/my-proj.my-ns.proxy$java.lang.Object$Callable$7da976d4
```

From what I found online, nothing can explain the meaning of this error

## Update

Thanks for the comments asking me to give more context.

I was able to understand that the error is coming from a macro I'm using.

In my code, I'm using the `time!` macro, from the metrics lib.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/metrics-clojure/metrics-clojure/blob/master/metrics-clojure-core/src/metrics/timers.clj#L113)this macro is using `proxy`

But this is not my code, is there a way to tell `yagni` not to look at it? (I guess not since it is a macro and compiled before `yagni` reads it)

Comment: Means what it says, no? "Could not find any references" -- saying something is unreferenced generally means it wasn't invoked, called, or... well... *referenced* (from any external entry point, exported interface, etc).

Comment: We can't say why that's true for your code when you don't *show* us that code (or, rather, the shortest possible similar code that unexpectedly generates the same warning). Add a [mre] to the question to make it answerable.